# asp.net mvc and grids which allow multiple row selections

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Is there JavaScript grid component where in read-only mode I would be able to select somehow several rows ( e.g. shift or ctrl with mouse click ) and track/process selected rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I've used [datatables.net](http://datatables.net/) previously. Awesome Javascript tables with [multiple user selection](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html) and server side processing.

Comment: +1 - DataTables is a really productive addition to your solutions toolkit.  It's a very straight forward and also allows you to simplify the backend as well.

Answer (score 1):

[jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) does this.